# PHP, quotes, and .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a bit of a brain fart with this one line:

```
jQuery("#image-div").html("<img src='get.php?id_no='" + id + ">");
```

I'm trying to concatenate the `<img>` tag with a variable `id` but I can't seem to get the quotes right. Stupid mistake, I know, but it's just eluding me. Can I get a little help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you were misplacing an apostrophe.

```
jQuery("#image-div").html("<img src='get.php?id_no=" + id + "'>");
```

Comment: Exactly this... sadly can't upvote, used my allowance for today.

Comment: you should probably invert your use of single and double quotes though.

Comment: It was misplaced rather than missing.

Comment: Damn, that was it. Thank you.. I couldn't see it!

Answer (score 1):

You have an misplaced single quote in your code.

```
jQuery("#image-div").html("<img src='get.php?id_no='" + id + ">");
                                                // ^ This one here
```

It should be

```
jQuery("#image-div").html("<img src='get.php?id_no=" + id + "'>");
                                                          // ^ Should be here
```

Comment: Yup, that was it.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I really don't to create DOM elements like you should be strict like:

```
jQuery("#image-div").appendTo(
                         $("<img/>")
                             .attr("src", "get.php?id_no" + id)
                             .attr("alt", "someThing") )
```

I know it is more typing but make more sense now.